# using one integer in multiple methods

Tags: java

So I'm working on something. To keep it short and simple, I have two classes. One class is where all the program is executed and the other class where I'm writing code that will be used. I have an x and a y integer in my class where all of the program is executed, and I need the method that will be executed to raise or lower the x or the y by 1. I have a switch statement where the person has four choices, and depending on which choice they make will decide if the x or the y rises or lowers in value.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Walking {
public void NorthSouthEastWest(){
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    boolean direction = false;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    do{String userDirection = input.nextLine();

        switch(userDirection){
            case "North":
                direction = true;
                y++;
                break;
            case "South":
                direction = true;
                y--;
                break;
            case "East":
                direction = true;
                x++;
                break;
            case "West":
                direction = true;
                x--;
                break;
            default:
    }
}while(direction == false);
```

but when I run the program, I print out the x and y before and after I type in the command for the switch statement, and the x and y just won't change. I'm unsure why. Any solutions?

Comment: First of all your syntax is incorrect while(direction == false); seems irrelevant

Comment: I understand you have x and y in both classes? So you change the one x in one class and print the other x in the other class?

Comment: @Akshay It's not incorrect. It would be better to write it as `while (!direction);`, but it's correct as-is.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen ..oops was about to say not a good practice

Comment: There are no prints in your code above, so we don't know where and how do you print them.

Comment: Is there any reason not to change the values in the method to attributes of the class?

Answer (score 3):

Primitives and primitive wrappers are immutable in Java, so a good solution would be to wrap them into an object that is mutable.

Below is an example using a `Location` class that holds your `x` and `y` coordinates.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Location location = new Location();
        Walking walking = new Walking();
        walking.northSouthEastWest(location);

        System.out.println(location.x);
        System.out.println(location.y);
    }
}

class Location {
    int x;
    int y;
}

class Walking {
    public void northSouthEastWest(Location location) {
        boolean direction = false;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            String userDirection = input.nextLine();

            switch (userDirection) {
                case "North":
                    direction = true;
                    location.y++;
                    break;
                case "South":
                    direction = true;
                    location.y--;
                    break;
                case "East":
                    direction = true;
                    location.x++;
                    break;
                case "West":
                    direction = true;
                    location.x--;
                    break;
            }
        } while (!direction);
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use a custom `Location`-like object, you could also use an `int[]` array with two elements.

Answer (score 2):

are you sure you're passing them(x & y) when you want to modify their values? Java doesn't pass method arguments by reference so you may want to look after that.

Answer (score 0):

The x and y variables are declared in the NorthSouthEastWest() method (by convention, methods in Java start with a lower case letter). They have local scope and are only visible in the method in which they were declared in.

If you want to access the x and y variables from another method, declare them as instance or class variables. Following link should help you understand the issue: [The Java Tutorials - Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

For example:

```
public class Walking {
    // These could also be declared as static variables 
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    // Rest of your code...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use such schema:

```
public class YourClass {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public void NorthSouthEastWest(){
//        your logic, don't do int x = 0; int y = 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();

        yourClass.printXY();

        yourClass.NorthSouthEastWest();

        yourClass.printXY();
    }

    public void printXY() {
        System.out.println("x=" + x + ", y=" + y);
    }
}
```

Comment: But then he gets x and y not back in his other class.

Comment: Won't change a thing. Primitive wrappers are immutable, same as primitives.

Comment: I tried it and got hopeful, but sadly, it did not raise the x and y I wanted it to. I'm not sure what it raised but it wasn't the x and y in the class i need. But thank you for the try c:

Comment: so I try the public int x and public in y, but when I try ti print them it tells me "non-static variable x can not be referenced in static context" and the same thing for y.

Comment: Right, do them static: public static int x;

Comment: Still won't work. The `NorthSouthEastWest` method is not static. Also, this approach no longer qualifies as OOP. Might as well dump everything in the main method at this rate.